# How can I reload React component based on URL set by sibling component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, render

I have `Main` component which holds the following code and it works fine.

```
<Switch>
<Route path='/compare' component={Compare} />
<Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
<Route path={`/search`} component={Search} />
<Route path={`/:vehicleId`} component={VehicleDetail} />
</Switch>
```

The `Search` component you see above has a search input box which when used show the search result. I want to get the search box out of the Search component and place it in my navigation bar, but show the result in Search component when searched from the navigation bar. Here is what my `App.js` looks like.

```
<div>
 <Navbar/> <-- search box is here now
 <Main/> <-- I have to show the result in here now, inside Search component
 <Footer/>
</div>
```

I am trying to set URL from `Navbar` component with the following code and it works perfectly fine.

```
this.props.history.push(`/search?q=${query}`)
```

However, only the URL gets updated, but the `Search` component does not re-render when I am already in the Search page. In other words, I can load the search component when I'm searching from another URL, but once I land in `domain.com/search?q=mercedes` I do not see the search result re-render if I search for let's say peugeot which updates the URL to `domain.com/search?q=peugeot` but still shows results from the last search which is `mercedes`.

How can I re-render the `Search` component?

**Further Info**
Search Component code is as follows:

```
state = {
        query   : (new URL(document.location)).searchParams.get('q'),
        submit  : false,
        result  : []
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.state.submit) {
            let url = `${data.api}api/all/?search=${this.state.query}`
            fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    this.setState({
                        result : data
                    })
                })
            this.setState({ submit : false })
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let url = `${data.api}api/all/?search=${this.state.query}`
        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({
                    result : data
                })
            })
    }
```

This works perfectly since the search box is within the search component. However, this code doesn't work when I am doing `history.push` and updating URL from sibling `Navbar` component.

Comment: Can we see how you are trying read this in your search component, I mean search component code?

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G Updated my question with search component code.

Comment: Can you debug to see if the control comes to componentDidUpdate ?

Comment: It does. I console logged a text and it shows whenever I search for something. But the component is not being updated.

Comment: Did you check in React developer tools, is the state of search component having the new data?

Comment: When I search from a different URL, it receives the data and shows it, but subsequent searches from the search result page does not get new data.

Comment: this.state.submit, where are you setting this to true? I don't see that anywhere in the code.

Comment: Well why do i ask this is because in componentDidUpdate you are checking  if (this.state.submit) so..

Comment: When I searched from inside the Search component I set `submit` to true on `handleSubmit` function whenever, the user wanted to search. After the search was complete I set this to false as you can see from the code I provided. Since I am searching from another component now, I think I need a way to set this to true. What can I do in this case?

Comment: Just for checking and confirming this, please set the submit to true and check whether it works.

Comment: or just remove the check, just for a quick confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in your **componentDidUpdate** you are checking for `this.state.submit` which is false hence it isn't working

Since now your in another component you need to find a way to set this submit in your state.

**Solution:**

Move all of your state and your `handleClick()` handler from **Header** to your **MainWrapper component**.
Then pass values as props to all components that need to share this functionality.

This way you can set **submit** in your state of the MainWrappercomponent and also access it in your child component via props.

Comment: Yep, if you ever find yourself trying to communicate between siblings, you probably need to hoist the logic up a level and pass it down as props.

Comment: I am using react router v4 and am confused as to how to pass props to `Search` component when my code is like this `<Route path={\`/search\`} component={Search} />`.

Comment: Why do you have to pass into Route? nope, I think you didn't understand, routing has nothing to do in this, its all about moving the state and the handler to wrapper components and then passing the handler down.

Comment: Please feel free to ask back if you still didn't get what I'am talking about.

Comment: I didn't get it brother. If I don't use `<Search prop1=func1 prop2=func2 />` how will I use those functions inside `Search` component?

Comment: please check this https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/